# Scraping flights data from www.kayak.it

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape the data from Kayak with Selenium, but my code doesn't work and I can't undertand why.

I have tried to close the privacy button in the following way, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

cookie_banner = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".onetrust-accept-btn-handler")

cookie_banner[0].click()

Can you help me? Thank you so much!

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

import sys
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import pandas
import json
import pprint

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36")

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

wd.get("https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210801,20210801") 

import pprint 
detail_travels = [] 
for travel in list_travels: 
   url = travel.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")[0].get_attribute("href")
   destination = "" 
   country = ""
   travel_id = ""
   if(len(travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".City__Name")) > 0): 
     destination = travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".City__Name")[0].text 
   if(len(travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Country__Name")) > 0):
     country = travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Country__Name")[0].text
   travel_id = url

   detail_travels.append({'url': url,
                        'destination': destination,
                        'country': country,
                        'travel_id': travel_id})

len(detail_travels)
pprint.pprint(detail_travels[0:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Selenium can be a bit too much overhead. Just spoofing what the page does in the browser tools, we find that this API is called:

https://www.kayak.it/s/horizon/exploreapi/destinations?airport=MIL&budget=&depart=20210801&return=20210801&duration=&exactDates=true&flightMaxStops=&stopsFilterActive=false&topRightLat=59.902761633461935&topRightLon=25.09658365167229&bottomLeftLat=26.101275008286677&bottomLeftLon=-6.719822598327707&zoomLevel=4&selectedMarker=&themeCode=&selectedDestination=

Maybe just using Python `requests` module and do a `get` to this URL you might be much better off. It will be necessary to fiddle a bit with the URL to get one the API does accept, but I would at least try this before working with the HTML rendered from the structured data...

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to use API, I'am start learning scraping just in this period. Is it possible that my code doesn't run because of the button of privacy that sometimes appears on the screen? In that case how can I close it? Thank you really much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to wait for the button to load before getting selenium to click it? When I tried to load the link in my browser, there was a slight delay before the privacy pop-up loaded.

Comment: I have added the following code but it doesn't work: 'time.sleep(3)

cookie_banner = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("button")
if len(cookie_banner) > 0:
  print('Privacy found')
  cookie_banner[0].click()'